# Dependent clause w/list *comma or semicolon* followed by independent clause

Tags: commas, lists, semicolons, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

Should we use a semicolon or comma when an adverbial dependent clause containing a list is followed by an independent clause?

While not everyone is a Newton, Einstein, or Hawking, every one of them is a fascinating character with a unique story.

or:

While not everyone is a Newton, Einstein, or Hawking; every one of them is a fascinating character with a unique story.

Comment: Both your examples, semantically, are meaningless.

Even if those weren't your own constructions, could you find some that seem to have no problem but their punctuation, please?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your example sentence as an issue beyond the comma.

The use of *everyone* clashes with *every one of them*.

To be grammatical, it needs to be rephrased in one of two ways:

> 1. While not everyone is a Newton, Einstein, or Hawking, **everyone** is a fascinating character with a unique story.
> 2. While **they aren't all** a Newton, Einstein, or Hawking, every one of them is a fascinating character with a unique story.

So, let's assume that the sentence has been corrected to one of those two versions.

In this particular construction, the sentence takes the form *while X, Y*.

Changing the comma to a semicolon would break that form and lead to confusion. (The *while x* would be stranded as a sentence fragment.)

---

On the other hand, if you *remove* **while**, you can use a semicolon without a problem—but only if you make some other changes.

For example:

> 1. Not everyone is a Newton, Einstein, or Hawking; **however,** everyone is a fascinating character with a unique story.
> 2. They aren't all a Newwon, Einstein, or Hawking; **but** every one of them is a fascinating character with a unique story.

Note that it is an erroneous belief that you can't start a sentence with *but*. See the blog post ["Can I Start a Sentence with a Conjunction?"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction?page=2) by Neal Whitman where this is discussed. Just as a sentence can start with *but*, so can a sentence continue with *but* after a semicolon.